# DataTable - First radio button of list never showing checked

Tags: html, radio-button, checked

I have a table with radio groups in the last column, where each group has a unique name.

I've set the first radio of each group as checked but for some weird reason the first row has all radios unchecked.

Inspecting the HTML I can see the 'checked' option on the first radio but it's displayed as unchecked.

Something like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>AAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td>
        <input name="row1" type="radio" checked>X
        <input name="row1" type="radio">Y
        <input name="row1" type="radio">Z
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>BBBBBBBBBBBB</td>
      <td>
        <input name="row2" type="radio" checked>X
        <input name="row2" type="radio">Y
        <input name="row2" type="radio">Z
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>CCCCCCCCCCCC</td>
      <td>
        <input name="row3" type="radio" checked>X
        <input name="row3" type="radio">Y
        <input name="row3" type="radio">Z
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

This only happens on the first row and is independent on the data. If the data changes or get sorted in a different way it's still the first row that has the issue.

EDIT: I've just figured out this is caused by jQuery DataTables but still don't know why. Here is an example to reproduce the issue https://jsfiddle.net/xkden3q8/

Comment: Without the source code we can only guess. Is the name of the radio buttons correct? What happens when you manually check one radio in the first row?

Comment: Thanks @Omagerio. I've added the table's code. As you can see is nothing fancy. If I click on the first radio then it works properly.

Comment: The HTML alone is working fine, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/pnzte92v/ 
You might have some conflict with the JS code

Comment: I know the HTML is fine, that's why I'm asking for help 

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with changing datatable library
 `<script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>`